# google sheet : generate increment number

Tags: google-sheets

I use this formula:

```
=filter(calc!B7:B,calc!P7:P="")
```

to display the data from Col B of 'calc' sheet where the Col P is  null or "".
it works fine and it will output single column. If i want to add index number (like incremental ID number) , i normally just manually add any formula that can generate increment number and it works.

But the problem is if the number of the output of that **filter()** was changed , then i have to readjust the index by extending it or deleting to match the number of the output.

I'm thinking if it's possible to embed the index number (increment number) into the formula itself , for example maybe like this :

```
=filter({ [my_index_number] , calc!B7:B },calc!P7:P="")
```

so to generate 2 column, where the left is the custom index_number column. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try on below formula. Adjust sheet name for other sheet. I have tested the formula to same sheet.

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SPLIT(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(FILTER(B7:B,P7:P="")))&"@"&FILTER(B7:B,P7:P=""),"@"),""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works on same sheet but when using reference to other sheet, it returns blank/empty, no error.

Comment: It must work for other sheet. Can you share a sample google-sheet so that I can put formula to that sheet. Also put here in comment which formula you tried.

Comment: try this formula `=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SPLIT(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(FILTER(calc!B7:B,calc!P7:P="")))&"@"&FILTER(calc!B7:B,calc!P7:P=""),"@"),""))`

Comment: Many Thanks, it works now. There's a typo problem when i typed the formula yesterday : calc -> calcc. I didn't look for the typing mistake because this formula didn't throw any error message/warning, it's just blank without any clue.

Comment: @andio Glad to know!